# Enable screen reader to not read class name, only read C# UI automation name

Tags: c#, xaml, accessibility, screen-readers

I am currently looking into accessibility option using AutomationProperty, one of the example provided was:

RadioButton Content="Canada" AutomationProperties.Name="Canada goose"

However, when using screen reader, it reads out "canada goose radio button", is there anyway to make it just read out "canada goose", and omit the "radio button", while still using radio button control.

Comment: To me this sounds like you want to *remove* a core piece of information that a user who relies on screen-reader technology will want to know by informing them they are currently on a radio button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With regards to C# UI automation specifically, I'm not sure if it's technically possible but if I relate it to html5, then yes, it is possible but highly discouraged.

In html, I could have `<input type=radio role=presentation>` but that would violate the 2nd rule of aria use - https://www.w3.org/TR/2013/WD-aria-in-html-20131003/#second-rule-of-aria-use.  It is valid html and would perform as you describe.  It would just read the label but not say it's a radio.

Of course, if it did that, the assistive technology user would have no idea it's a radio button and would not be able to interact with it so the radio button would be useless.